# PagerAdapter setCurrentItem equivalent?

Tags: android

My adapter extends PagerAdapter not ViewPager. I am looking for similar method as setCurrentItem() to make Next/Previous button. Could you recommend me?

I have added some code. So could anyone recommend me maybe how I could refactor my adapter the right way?

MyAdapter

```
public class CardsViewPager extends PagerAdapter {

Context context;
List<Card> cardList;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public CardsViewPager(Context context, List<Card> cards) {
    this.context = context;
    this.cardList = cards;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cardList.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ScrollView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_card, container, false);

    TextView mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_card_title);
    mTitle.setText(cardList.get(position).getTitle());

    TextView mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_card_description);
    mDescription.setText(cardList.get(position).getDescription());

    ImageView imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_card_image);
    Glide.with(context).load(cardList.get(position).getImage()).into(imageView);

    container.addView(itemView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "you clicked image " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

}

MyActivity

```
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myCustomPagerAdapter.setCurrentItem(getItem(+1), true); //getItem(-1) for previous
        }
    });
}

private int getItem(int i) {
    return myCustomPagerAdapter.getCurrentItem() + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, other than to pass the `ViewPager` into the `PagerAdapter` and then call `setCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager`. `PagerAdapter` itself has no concept of "current".

Comment: I have added my code. Could you please recommend me how I can refactor it to ViewPager? Please

Comment: @BorisRuzanov: If your activity has the `ViewPager`, your activity can call `getCurrentItem()` and `setCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager`. If your activity does not have the `ViewPager`, then it should not have the `PagerAdapter` either.